# Возможна ли ручная реализация VPN соединения внутри приложения в обход системных API?

Tags: c++, winapi, macos, vpn

Я ещё не знаю как внутри устроена технология VPN соединений, поэтому перед тем как начну тратить кучу времени на её изучение и реализацию на C++ через сокеты хочу уточнить: есть ли смысл? Не заблокирует ли система попытки приложения стать клиентом удалённой сети в обход RasAPI (Windows) или MacOS-интерфейса для VPN (который, кстати, доступен только платному аккаунту разработчика)?
Если это реально, посоветуйте пожалуйста с чего начать.

*PS: под VPN я имею ввиду не OpenVPN со своим сервером, а стандартное соединение PPTP или L2TP/IPSec, которое будет "дружить" с VPN-сетями, создаваемыми физическим оборудованием (Цисками, Д-линками корпоративными и т.д.).*

Comment: Если подходящее оборудование есть, то все можно вскрыть...

Comment: Как и любой другой протокол, PPTP или L2TP, это всего лишь набор байт, передаваемый по каналу связи, следующий некому стандарту кодирования. PPTP это протокол сетевого уровня OSI, использующий свой идентификатор протокола (47). Таким образом для его реализации вам потребуется использовать raw socket. Большинство ОС позволяют работать с такими сокетами (часто, только привилегированным процессам)

Comment: @Mike, благодарю! Вопрос снят... Raw socket к сожалению не подходит - клиент должен работать даже из под гостевой учётки, а к сырым сокетам только админ имеет доступ, поэтому не судьба ((